# Liferay custom single-sign-on with redirect and parameters

Tags: authentication, liferay, parameter-passing, single-sign-on, hook

this is my first question here and it's quite tricky as i didn't find enough relevant resources on the web. So I really hope, to get some help with this:

I am doing a custom single-sign-on with Liferay 6.2 GA4. Therefore I have developed a custom login-hook, that can handle my URL that looks like:

http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login?q=10C7vCMqv%2BlYThuxjdOmbUIXj1LKz9W3s5IUg%2F8H%2FvqRPUGOuzoC7pRT4hwVp2TpLf%2FnDRaGfpvoubhvSxlhidyX1SAowlvhdeWb95xRyxyCGZmKxE%2FZejk%2BIS5PvVHYIprBmM5Ec1cM%2Fq5dd5OGpEJJislrctRP

From this i decode the q-parameter to get the login parameters and other parameters, that i need to decide on which page I get redirected and i pass the attribute to the request

```
request.setAttribute("myParam", recordId);
```

and

```
return credentials;
```

I have also a LoginPostAction, that gets called afterwards and here it is, where it gets tricky:

```
public final void run(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ActionException {
    ...
    final PortletURL redirectURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(
        request, "portlet_WAR_myportlet",
  >>>>  PortalUtil.getPlidFromPortletId(???, "portlet_WAR_myportlet"),
        PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);

        redirectURL.setParameter("myParam", String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("myParam")));

        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL.toString());
}
```

So, I have the portlet name (PortletId) but I cannot get the Plid from this, as i don't have the ThemeDisplay at this time.

First question: How can i create a PortletURL at this time, which i can use in sendRedirect()?
Second: I have also tried to setAttribute and hardcode the sendRedirect("/urlToMyPortlet"), but I cannot use this at this time anymore as it gets lost afterwards (and is null) when i try to get it on the next page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance,
rom12three

Comment: PortalUtil.getPlidFromPortletId(groupId, portletId) require groupId, do you have groupId?

Comment: Also, if you pass a hard-coded URL then you just have only choice of passing parameter as queryString and extract it from httpServletRequest object.